# Matching a string value to an imported excel sheet cell

Tags: c#, excel, ip, match

I am pretty sure I am REALLY close to having this figured out. I have thousands of IP addresses in an excel document imported. I input an IP and I want it so the program matches that IP address with the closest IP address in the excel sheet and then prints to the console. I think my problem is in my first if statement where I am parsing the worksheet. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I get an error message Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not to an instance of an object. It then gives a path of my excel sheet, followed by the exception I guess assuming it is at the first if statement.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Investigations
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {



            IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse("8.8.8.8");
            IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(addr);
            Console.WriteLine("IP Address: " + addr);
            Console.WriteLine("Host Name: " + entry.HostName);


            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\subnets.xlsx");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;


            bool foundIP = false;
            IPAddress excelIP = IPAddress.Parse("8.8.8.8");

            for (int i = 0; i < xlWorksheet.Rows.Count; i++)
            {


                if (IPAddress.TryParse(xlWorksheet.Cells[i + 1, 1].Value.ToString(), out excelIP))
                    Console.WriteLine(excelIP);
                {

                    // Compare the IP address we found with the one we're looking for                 
                    if (excelIP.Equals(addr))
                    {
                        foundIP = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (foundIP)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found the IP address!");
                Console.WriteLine(excelIP);

                }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found the IP address!");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Is your code correct above? because you have a single executable line of code after your first `if` and the rest is just an unrelated block of code that will always try to run. You probably need to move the line `Console.WriteLine(excelIP);` inside the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you declare the range object (used rows and columns)
but then iterate through the worksheets rows (all rows used or not in the worksheet).

try

```
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

for (int i = 0; i < xlRange.Rows.Count; i++)
```

...

Comment: Not quite, still giving me the same handling exception as before

Comment: I guess i don't see in your question where you mention an exception being thrown. Maybe try updating it to be more specific?

Comment: Another thing i see that is maybe missing is a for to iterate through the columns.

xlWorksheet.Cells[i + 1, 1]

should probably be inside a for(int i =0, i < xlRange.Columns.Count; i++)

Comment: "can not perform runtime binding on a null reference" and it is always at the first if statement.

Comment: Is your code correct above? because you have a single executable line of code after your first `if` and the rest is just an unrelated block of code. You probably need to move the line `Console.WriteLine(excelIP);` inside the `if` block. Otherwise the block of code after that will run even when `excelIP` is null.

Comment: I have updated the code where I am at, still getting that null reference, on the first if statement.

Comment: @LeGreen95 could you also edit the question to include the exception error message

Comment: I updated you with the error message in the question. Sorry for the inconvenience.